# How to append %fromhost-ip% variable to every log line in rsyslog for remote host logs?

Tags: linux, logging, remote, syslog

I use rsyslog variables to compose log filenames. Variables %HOSTNAME% and %fromhost-ip%. Everything is OK, but the question is:
How can I append/prepend these variables to every log line for logs comming from remote hosts?

Answer (score 5):

The solution is to use custom rsyslog templates. First you create the log message template.
The following template resembles the default syslog format but has the `%fromhost-ip%` added you can add other variables in the same manner

```
$template tplremote,"%timegenerated% %HOSTNAME% %fromhost-ip% %syslogtag%%msg:::drop-last-lf%\n"
```

Then we create the file name template:

```
$template RemoteHost,"/var/log/remote/%HOSTNAME%.log"
```

And finally, we tell rsyslog to use created templates:

```
if ($hostname != 'localhost') then ?RemoteHost;tplremote  
& ~
```

Note, the last lines must be added right before the line containing.

```
*.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none
```

Also note that this was tested and worked in the fresh rsyslog from epel repo on redhat (`rsyslog-7.6.7-1.el6.x86_64`). The behaviour might be different in other distros.

Comment: Needs more upvotes! Thanks. rsyslog complained `~` was deprecated and to use `stop`. `localhost` didn't work; $hostname resolved instead to the unqualified host name.